# TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Tags: python

What's going on here?

Here's the error:

```
for j in range(len(rotlati)):   
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

The code is:

```
vv = np.matrix([0, 0]).T
rotlati = float(vv[0])
latidef = np.zeros(22)

for j in range(len(rotlati)):
    latidef[j] = rotlati[j]
```

Answer (score 7):

The error is exactly what is says it is. `rotlati` is a `float`.  You cannot take the `len()` of a `float`.  Looking at your code, it looks as if you might have *meant* to create **lists** called `rotlati` and `rotlongi` and append to them on each iteration of your `range(len(lati))` loop.  Instead you're currently just overwriting the same two floating-point variables on every iteration.

Answer (score 4):

The len argument may be a sequence (string, tuple or list) or a mapping (dictionary).
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len

Before calling the len function, you should verify if the argument is one of this type. You can call the method isinstance() to verify it. Take a look on how to use it.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance

Answer (score 1):

Another scenario i got the same error, while saving file.

odf.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=str(x),startcol=5,index=False)

You may also check the name of the sheet is int or float. Convert that to string.

Answer (score 1):

It's common to get this error due to unexpected/"hidden" NaN values.

For example, suppose you have a list or a pandas Series (or any collection) of strings that was processed elsewhere and you want to find the length of each string. If this list contains a NaN, then the error in the title occurs.

```py
lst = ['hello', float('nan'), 'hola']    # <---- has NaN
[len(x) for x in lst]                    # <---- TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

You'll probably have your own way of handling these NaNs. For me, one way is to perform a conditional check and call `len()` only if it's not NaN.

For example, the below code finds the length of an element only if it equals itself (NaN doesn't equal itself) and do nothing otherwise.

```py
[len(x) if x == x else x for x in lst]
# [5, nan, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the correct answer, try this:

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}

alice = {

    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {

    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

numbers = []

def average(numbers):

    total = float(sum(numbers))
    return total / len(numbers)
```